# Spike killer - Why does it reduce spikes?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, efficiency

[This application note](https://www.toshiba-tmat.co.jp/pdf/en/product/3-1_am_parts_absse.pdf) says that the spikes when the diode stops conducting its due to its reverse recovery time.

[image]

[image]

I thought that the spikes were occuring due to the parastic inductance and the capacitance of the diode. As there is a huge di/dt during the transition between ON and OFF state of the diode, the parasitic inductance induce a voltage which oscillates with the diode capacitances. If you add some inductance on the wire, the slope di/dt will be reduced and then the voltage across the inductance will be lower, and the spike of the oscillation would be lower.

Here is their explanation, I would take a spike killer with a BH - curve with a little slope dB/dH for having inductance. It will increase the losses.

[image]

[image]

In any case I know that I am wrong, but why? Why does the reverse recovery time of the diode have an influence on the spikes?

Comment: What is the schematic associated with the first picture?

Comment: First thing to do ... Simulate in a simple schematic using 2 diodes (one fast, one slow) to see what happen ...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I do not think that is really dependant on the type of converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple circuit to show how a "bead" "interact" with the diode. NB: 1N4148 is a little "overloaded" ... :-)

EDIT : case where one diode wire was inserted through ferrite bead.

*This kind of bead (Amobead) insert a higher "inductance" below one frequency ... and/ or a "higher impedance", serially with the diode and lowering di/dt and so "interferences".* I have not found usefull datas about, except some "research paid papers".

Example of Ferritebead behavior microcap v12 included files. (see equivalent imaginary part, L increasing a "little much"...)

( http://spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm)

[image]

I add also an expanded view for the fast diode.

Other behavior of bead considered as a coupled "transformer"  (coupling = 1, no in realty ...).

Note that "bead" suppress only "oscillations". Diodes don't go "really faster".

[image]
[image]

And here, two new views when Rs=10 (as example, only for showing effects) and coupling factor is 0.9 (as example too ...).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your simulation is showing a higher di/dt with a bead ? Why did you remove the inductance from the left schematic on the right schematic ? Why  "bead is same that a coupled "transformer" (coupling = 1)" ? Why can you put a 1 OHm resistor across this transformer ?

Comment: di/dt is the same at beginning. It simply stops before. I did not remove the inductance in the left schematic ... the wire pass "through" a toroidal bead, unless I am wrong, and the secondary is made by the material of the bead ("conducting a little", this is the resistance) so it can be seen as a "transformer" with "secondary short-circuited".

Comment: This is not clear to me.  There is an inductance in one circuit and in the other there is no inductance and you replace the inductance by a transformer. So we saw the effect of the transformer and the inductance as this is the difference between the two circuits. Ferrite material is not really conducting (not 10 Ohm at least) and this resistance affects the behavior of the whole circuit, so i do not think that the simulation is really modeling what is happening. In any case your simulation is showing the effects and not the causes of ringing.

Comment: The inductance used is 5nH (! some mm of wire), which would be, at least, the inductance of the short wire used to connect the diode. When you use a ferrite bead, in old times, you had to pass the wire through the hole of the bead. And the ferrite has "some"  losses dues to his behavior and "components" used (which I don't "know"). Beads are used to "stop" interference's" generated by circuitry and in this case by the "diode" when it switch off (internal parasitic's HF resistance, self and "capacitors" at least ...).

Comment: "Beads" can be also "inserted" components serial with the diodes. In this case, they can be viewed as opposing a high "impedance" at high frequencies, which then are "suppressed" . Note that the K I used in the above pictures for transformer was almost 1. In fact, it may be a function of frequency.

Comment: I agree about what you are saying. But the original question was why does the reverse recovery time of the diode have an influence on the spikes? I am asking why. I do not doubt about the effects that TOSHIBA show us as you showed  us too.

Comment: There is a "charge" (dq/dt) to be recovered in the diode when it is on ... which can't be done instantly and generates high frequencies interference's, thus "spikes" (because of the presence internally of inductor and capacitor). It is a problem at "physical" level.

Answer (score 2):

The bead is so engineered to have high inductance at only 2 specific field/current values: \$H_{s+}\$ and \$H_{s-}\$. These are the two magnetic field values where the hysteresis curve goes essentially vertical. Apart from these two toggle points, its inductance is essentially zero. Therefore, it will reduce \$dI/dt\$ only while \$I\$ has to cross these two current limits.

Besides the positive effect demonstrated excessively, there is also a bad effect which is only hinted at in sector "V": The inductor slows the turn on of the Diode after the MOSFET switches off. As a result, there will be a worse negative spike at the switch node than without the bead.